# Mapstruct: Cannot convert from java.time.LocalDate to java.time.OffsetDateTime

Tags: java-time, mapstruct

```
public class ClassA {
     private OffsetDateTime updateBy;
}

public class ClassB {
     private LocalDate timestamp;
}

public interface ClassABMapper {
     @Mapping(target = "updateBy", source = "classB.timestamp")
     ClassA map(ClassB classB);
}
```

> Can't map property "java.time.LocalDate timestamp" to "java.time.OffsetDateTime updateBy". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "java.time.OffsetDateTime map(java.time.LocalDate value)".

I tried declaring the following method in mapper.

```
java.time.LocalDate map(java.time.OffsetDateTime value);
```

And I am getting error:

> error: java.time.LocalDate does not have an accessible empty constructor.
>           java.time.LocalDate map(java.time.OffsetDateTime value);

Can someone please explain how to perform the conversion?

Answer (score 1):

I created my own custom mapper as explained in the documentation [section 5.4. Invoking other mappers](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#invoking-other-mappers). That solved this issue for me.